# octave error: subs: we do not support single-input w/ substitution from workspace

Tags: matlab, octave

So I am writing a matlab code for bisection method of finding roots.  I do not have acseess to matlab so I am using GNU octave the following is my code:

```
a=3*pi/2; b=2*pi; dig=35;
n=0;
x=0;

for tol=[.5e-7 .5e-15 .5e-33]
  [n,x]=sbisec(dig,a,b,tol)
end

n=0;
function [ntol,x]=sbisec(dig,a,b,tol)
  ntol=ceil(log((b-a)/tol)/log(2));
  digits(dig);
  a=vpa(a); 
  b=vpa(b);
    for n=1:ntol
      x=vpa((a+b)/2);
      fx=subs(f(x));
    if fx<0
      a=x;
    else
      b=x;
    end
    end
endfunction

function y=f(x)
y=cos(x)*cosh(x)-1;
endfunction
```

Which when I run the flile.m I get the following error

```
error: subs: we do not support single-input w/ substitution from workspace
```

So is from the error I am thinking this is a octave problem but I do not know.

My question is what does this error mean and what I'm I doing to cause it.

Comment: That's not an Octave error. That is coming from the function `subs` which is part of the symbolic package. You are calling the `subs` function incorrectly, it needs at least two arguments.  See `help '@sym/subs'`. And if you take a look at the source code of `subs` (run `type '@sym/subs'`), you will see that you get that error message when `nargin == 1`

Comment: basically i had to find a matlab capable machine since the error comes from octaves incopacity to handle @sym